# StreamWriter creating Directory instead of File

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

Really confused here. I'm running Windows 7 and on an Administrator account, but for some reason, the following code is falling down;

```
public static readonly string Report = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "report.csv");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Report, true);
```

I get the following error;

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Trent\Desktop\report.csv' is denied.

Then, when I look on the Desktop I have a Folder called "report.csv" instead of a file...
I know it's probably something really basic, but I have no idea what it is, anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you delete that folder from the desktop and try again? I am suspecting, it got created before and as a result, your current code is failing.

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly

Comment: What if you try another folder? Like old stand-by C:\TEMP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code you are creating that directory. Either that, or it's been there all along.

Dig through the rest of your code looking for where you use the `Report` field.

The code you have posted is fine.

Comment: Yeahh -_- Silly me...using the wrong code to check for/delete the file if it already exists. Thanks guys!